# Log out dialog focused on second monitor in multi-monitor setup (openSUSE KDE)

Tags: linux, kde, opensuse, multi-monitor

Whenever I invoke the log out / shutdown dialog, the focus is on the secondary monitor, i.e. keyboard moves options showing up in the secondary monitor. Even if that monitor is turned off. What's odd is that at session unlock dialog the primary monitor gets the focus.

I want the primary monitor (DP-1) to get the focus. What's missing?

Kscreen is disabled, as it was causing issues (black/no background on the primary every once in a while, only the KDE main panel).

/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-monitor.conf:

```
Section "Monitor"
  Identifier    "DP-1"

  Option        "Primary"   "true"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
  Identifier    "HDMI-1"

  Option        "RightOf"   "DP-1"
EndSection
```

Config:

```
> xrandr --listmonitors 
Monitors: 2
 0: +*DP-1 2560/527x1440/296+0+0  DP-1
 1: +HDMI-1 2560/526x1440/296+2560+0  HDMI-1
```

Comment: From `man xrandr` I gather that *primary* means almost nothing, but the issue stands anyway.

Comment: Switched cables, and now GRUB appears on the secondary monitor...just to make matters worse :(

Comment: Looks like it's a bug https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=390503